# Как скачать файлы из интернета и запаковать в zip архив

Tags: zip

Есть какие-нибудь утилиты консольные для скачивания файлов из интернета и последующей упаковкой их в zip-архив?

В принципе, меня устраивало решение на PHP: https://pastebin.com/aGP3v9f1

```
<?php

$files = array("https://psv4.userapi.com/c8v-S-9gzSq8vydjNgqfBtzkDw&dl=1", "https://psv4.userapi.com/c8484axP3xgCN_5m2y54CTxv-A&dl=1", "https://psv4.userapi.com/c84jNA3g9ShMlvPtHPFihMSpHUadQ1x0w&dl=1", "https://psv4.userapi.com/c848324zlE6BHXQGb6FSK0CoM7uYy5Zf4xJ5xA&dl=1", "https://psv4.userapi.com/c848216qawEJpS5sTmiLcsFngjdCat8rwch-hcfQUyg&dl=1", "https://psv4.userapi.com/c84833-vTHZGigvUoc43_OWFogouFxNQ4oY1Dw&dl=1", "https://psv4.userapi.com/c848432/u1992XAfzytejYWx-roFg&dl=1", "https://psv4.userapi.com/c848432/u19993nSs17sLeT5KO1EZ-Ufmi38VZwpQ&dl=1", "https://psv4.userapi.com/c848136/u19993692LvQVhJu3VTxdkewAXYZi4fw&dl=1", "https://psv4.userapi.com/c848016/u19991KvAHLrsUqYRwJGiSUcSFlpRpg&dl=1", "https://psv4.userapi.com/c848236/u1999369p0dFxxDGhebsFRblC3siC9TM5CA&dl=1", "https://psv4.userapi.com/c848124/u199936922FlxMD9vaflHyyACBqhJIUL_0d86hp2cZNtA7uf0b4A&dl=1", "https://psv4.userapi.com/c848336/u1999369221wJGcxF9YVeFT-4gFp1yDRRx5PtzUwOdDLJCg&dl=1",);

# create new zip object
$zip = new ZipArchive();

# create a temp file & open it
$tmp_file = tempnam('.', '');
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

# loop through each file
foreach ($files as $file) {

$ch = curl_init($file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if ($status == 200) {
    #add it to the zip
    $zip->addFromString(basename($file), $output);
    //file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/audio.mp3', $output);
}



}

# close zip
$zip->close();

# send the file to the browser as a download
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="my file.zip"');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($tmp_file);
unlink($tmp_file);
?>
```

Но работает некорректно при упаковке 10+ файлов, некоторые файлы оказываются пустыми в 0 байт.

Comment: Есть. curl и zip, как ни странно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы скачиваете слишком быстро файлы в одном потоке, с одного IP. Сервер с которого вы качаете, может воспринимать такие действия как ДДОС-атаку. Попробуйте добавить sleep(3) в конце цикла foreach, где идет перебор файлов. Так ваш скрипт будет ждать 3 секунды перед тем, как закачать новый файл.

Comment: Да этого я не учел что на сервере могут быть проверки на количество запросов с одного ip за определенный интервал времени, жаль... но видимо кроме как использовать прокси в curl не как это не решить. А по поводу 3 секундного интервала между запросами это мне не подходит слишком долго.